# Adding sms functionality to MySQL

Tags: mysql

A newbie in database constuction, need help in adding automated sms functionality in mysql database. A user needs to sent a certain sms with certain keywords like 'location' to the system. the system refines a search according to the location content then sents back the data back to the user.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know MySQL (nor any other RDBMS) does not provide this kind of functionality, and I highly doubt that most ever will. This kind of problem is more the domain of a server program listening for SMS messages, that program then querying the database, and that program then relaying the results back via SMS.